# How to use array in Wordpress via WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to put a variable inside a wp_query but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$stuff = array('easy','medium','hard');

$loop = new WP_Query('category='.$stuff.'&order=asc');

while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$stuff = array(
'cat' => array('easy', 'medium', 'hard'),
'orderby' => 'title',
'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);

$loop = new WP_Query($stuff);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to concatenate an array (`$stuff`) in middle of your string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'cat' is for cat id's
try:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff,news' );
```

or

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

read this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: Didn't you want `category__in`?